# I typed "icov -f UTF-8 file" to the executable, the output was "illegal input sequence at position 24"

Tags: c++, file, debugging, gcc, binary

My binary compiled by `g++`, when I try to open it with `gdbgui` (written in python), it read it with `utf-8`, then shows me this error:

```
&#39;utf-8&#39; codec can&#39;t decode byte 0xf0 in position 24: invalid continuation byte
```

How can I fix this error manually, because I don't know how start to see the source for looking for the error with detail.

I typed `icov -f UTF-8 file` and the terminal said me that

```
ELF>iconv: illegal input sequence at position 24
```

That is not seen good in the text, but the output is this:

[image: Output of iconv of the file]

---

**Output of `file main`:**

```
$ file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=15d8a314b52498b7f0a6f16aec116e66d72fe589, not stripped
```

---

**Output of `file -i main`:**

```
$ file -i main
main: application/x-sharedlib; charset=binary
```

---

**The C++ source:**

```
int main(){
  int x,y;
  x=13;
  y=9;
  if(x==y){
    x=17;
  } else{
    x=23;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You tried to change the text encoding of a binary file? Did you even compile with debug flags?

Comment: No, I didn't try it. I don't know how to use it with flags.